# Complex Analysis; Serge Lang; Ex II.3.2

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve:

> Show that there exists $r>0$ such that if $|z|<r$ then $$\log \exp z=z.$$

I think that for this problem I am expected to use Theorem 3.2,

> **Theorem 3.2.** Let$f(T)=\sum a_{n} T^{n}$ be a non-constant power series, having a non-zero radius of convergence. If $f(0)=0,$ then there exists $s>0$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ with $|z| \leqq s,$ and $z \neq 0.$

But I am not sure that I understand how to apply this. I know that if $x>0$ is real then we have the identity,
$$\exp \log x = x.$$
Furthermore, the power series expansion for $\exp$ has an infinite radius of convergence while the power series expansion for $\log x$ holds true for $0<x<2.$ So then when $x$ is real and $|x-1|<1$ we have that,
$$\exp \log x = x.$$
I am not sure how to establish this claim directly for complex numbers.

Comment: The first question that must be asked is: what branch of the logarithm function are we discussing? For example, the result is obviously false if $\log$ returns values in the strip $\Bbb R\times i[2\pi, 4\pi)$.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, thee question did not mention anything about the branch of the logarithm.

Comment: How does Lang define $\log w$?

Comment: You cannot just talk about "the" log function on complex numbers. $w = e^z = e^{z + n2\pi i}$ for integer $n$. Therefore in order to have a well-defined inverse of the exponential function, you have to choose which of those infinitely many values $z+n2\pi i$ is the one you are going to call "$\log w$". Usually, this is chosen to be continuous, so that $\log w$ takes its values in a strip of the form $\Bbb R + i[\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi)$ or $\Bbb R + i(\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi]$ for some fixed $\alpha$. Such a strip is called a branch of the logarithm. Your result is only true for certain branches.